# Most compact way to store argv into variable with default value in Python

Tags: python, argv

Perl has the following syntax:

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0] || "defaultfile.txt";
```

So when the code has no argument it will automatically take `defaultfile.txt` as the value for `$filename`.

What's the Python way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for the most compact way and the Python way.

For a compact way, I'd use

```
filename = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else 'defaultfile.txt'
```

But I think the Pythonic way is to do it right immediately, and use a module like `argparse` to parse arguments. It seems slight overkill for a single argument but it gives you a usage message and an obvious way to expand the code when you want to add options, extra arguments, and so on.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("filename", nargs='?', default="defaultfile.txt",
                    help="File to process, default is 'defaultfile.txt.")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Now filename is in args.filename
print args.filename
```

You get some helpful functionality immediately:

```
$ python test.py
defaultfile.txt

$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [filename]

positional arguments:
  filename    File to process, default is 'defaultfile.txt'

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the Python way would be

```
try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    filename = "defaultfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you should do something like [what Remco suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22475166/1561811).

But the literal translation of `my $filename = $ARGV[0] || "defaultfile.txt";` (as far as I can tell; I don't know Perl) is `filename = sys.argv[0] or 'defaultfile.txt'`. This will set `filename` to `sys.argv[0]` if it's non-empty (or rather, *truey*), or else to `'defaultfile.txt'`. Note that it *will* raise an exception if `sys.argv` itself is empty.

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more information on truth value and Python's Boolean operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple function to make it more compact:

```
def list_get (l, idx, default):
  try:
    return l[idx]
  except IndexError:
    return default
```

Then:

```
filename = list_get(sys.argv, 1, "defaultfile.txt")
```